# redis_client::get takes more than a second to reply

Tags: c++, redis

I posted this question on Redis git hub, I will update both sides if I see any reply.

running C++ on VisualStudio 2015, x64

I noticed that calling "get" takes almost 2 seconds to return a value.
my key is "Control:107:1"; I am running a Redis server on my local machine; it has about 200 keys.

I even deconstructed the command : redis_client->get(key).get() so I can measure timing - here is my code:

```
<...snip...>
cpp_redis::future_client* redis_client = new cpp_redis::future_client();
redis_client::connect(host, port, nullptr);
<...snip...>

string r;

auto startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

auto get = redis_client->get(key); 

auto endTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
__int64 iDiff2 = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endTime - startTime).count()) / 1000;
std::cout << "redis_client->get(" << key << ") " << iDiff2 << std::endl;  

auto val = get.get();

auto endTime2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
__int64 iDiff3 = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endTime2 - endTime).count()) / 1000;
std::cout << "get.get() " << iDiff3 << std::endl;

if (!val.is_null() && val.is_string())
{
    auto startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    r = val.as_string();

    auto endTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    __int64 iDiff2 = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endTime - startTime).count()) / 1000;
    std::cout << "val.as_string() " << iDiff2 << std::endl;
}

return r;
```

my result prints are:

redis_client->get(Control:107:1) 0

get.get() 1939

val.as_string() 0

I get similar results whe
ther the key exists or not.

(please note that when I print the measured microseconds I divide by 1000, so the printing is in milliseconds!)

please help me understand....
thank you
Mia

Comment: Anyone interested in the details can find our discussion on this topic at Github: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/4930

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bottom line:
 my Redis server version was very old. 
with newer versions I experienced better "get" times as you can see in the details as pointed by Tomasz Poradowski in the comment

I hope someone (maybe resurrect MS OpenTech?) revives windows support for Redis server advanced versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [bredis](https://github.com/basiliscos/cpp-bredis) (disclaimer: I'm an author of it): it does not uses official redis parser (`hiredis` library), that's why it perfectly compiles on Windows. It depends on boost (`boost::asio`) library, which also works fine on Windows.